# Binding for visibility not updating when suspending

Tags: c#, windows-8, winrt-xaml, suspend

My .xaml code has some buttons whose visibility is tied to a variable (true=visible, false=not visible). This works fine with everything I do EXCEPT for when I hit the start/windows button. My 'OnSuspending' method should be setting this variable to false, but if I go to start and then reopen the program the buttons are still visible.

I seem to be suspending correctly, since everything else there works as expected, so I suspect the .xaml page just isn't updating when the variable is changed to be false during suspension. Why is this?

Comment: Maybe relevant: it seems to work properly if I leave the tablet alone for so long it falls asleep before reopening the program.

Comment: Did you place a break point in OnSuspending? Does it break when you are attempting to shutdown? You might need to log it if you can't see it.

Comment: When run on a simulator, it hits the breakpoints I place in OnSuspending. I did notice that this problem does not occur on the simulator when I tell it to suspend. When I put it on the tablet to run, however, it does not function when I hit the Windows Button to go to start. It *does* work correctly when I suspend by side-swiping to a different app.

Comment: Have you used INotifyPropertyChanged??

Comment: Yes, I'm using OnPropertyChanged (which uses PropertyChangedEventArgs). Like I said it works anytime I'm not using the windows key specifically. I'm starting to wonder if going to the start menu is actually supposed to suspend application? I thought it did since the only other thing in my OnSuspend (turning off a camera) does occur when going to start. Maybe I'm not suspending at all but something else is turning my camera off?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going to the Start menu does NOT suspend your app.

It occludes your app, which is different.

Comment: Yeah, that'd do it. So I guess my next question is 'how can I tell my code to do something when it becomes occluded'? Thanks for your help!